# How to integrate Product Designer Plugin (Built in Magento) to my existing site built in PHP?

Tags: product, php

I run an online t-shirt designing company. We've built our site using - Flash Design tool and built the complete site in PHP (Code Ignitor). As the existing design tool is built in Flash, it is less responsive. We want to integrate this tool - http://www.designnbuy.com/all-in-one-designer-html5.html But they wanted us to convert the existing site to magento platform , then only they would be able to integrate.

I've spent good amount of time and energy in building the complete website including the back end framework needed for printing shipping labels to production. I would prefer not to migrate the entire site to Magento. Is there any way I can integrate my existing site built in PHP and the tool built using Magento?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you contact cart2cart who specialize in migrating sites like yours to Magento.